# Debugging a remote function in Julia

Tags: debugging, julia

I'm getting a DomainError in my remote function and I was wondering if there is a way to debug the error. I'm running:

```
@sync for i=1:n_machines
    refs[i] = @spawnat machines[i] run_gibbs(X_distributed, dpmm, mult, z)
end
```

I don't believe Debug package supports distributed code. I've also tried Gallium, however, the distributed data array X does not get passed to the function when I enter:

```
@enter run_gibbs(X_distributed, dpmm, mult, z)
```

What is the best way to debug code in a remote function call in Julia?

Comment: My guess is you're getting an unhelpful stack trace? If so, this patch will hopefully fix it: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/21776.

Comment: that would be fantastic!